# How to do a regexp to test if a string includes -0 or -1?

Tags: javascript, regex

Im not exactly sure how to do this since it includes the `-`. I need to test both cases. I am pretty sure that you use the `/` to escape special characters but I tried `RegExp(\/-0 /-1\).test(string)` and had no luck what so ever. I am new to RegExp.

Comment: No, the escape character is the backslash, and the regex literal delimiter is the forward slash.

Comment: `RegExp(/-0|-1/).test(string)`

Comment: Did you even look at one example of a regex in JavaScript? Sorry to say, but this shows no research effort.

Comment: @S.Jovan that worked thank you :) put it as an answer

Comment: You can use `/-[01]/.test(string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-[01]
```

- `-` Match this literally
- `[01]` Match `0` or `1`

```js
var a = ["-1", "-0", "1", "0", "-2"]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(/-[01]/.test(s))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your backslashes backwards, also here's the code

```
(/-0|-1/g).test(string);
```

Comment: without the `[]` it works , otherwise 0 and 1 work alone. example `ihoioiiokjh0` returns true.

Comment: No need for `g` flag. Also no need to wrap the regex pattern in parentheses